# Workbooks.Open Method in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

My vba script in **myMacro.xls** `Workbooks.Open` Method work well as below,

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\ExcelMacroProj\myTest.xls", ReadOnly:=True
```

But when I try to change the `Filename` value to a new path as below, but all my practices didn't work. Show **Run time error 1004**.

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="myTest.xls", ReadOnly:=True
or
Workbooks.Open Filename:="./myTest.xls", ReadOnly:=True
or
Workbooks.Open Filename:=".\myTest.xls", ReadOnly:=True
```

Actually **myMacro.xls** and **myTest.xls** was placed in the same folder. That's why I want to change to a flexible folder directory.

how could I fix this issue? Appreciated for your read and reply.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might try using `ThisWorkbook.Path` to make an absolute path. It returns the folder path of the workbook running the macro (excluding the filename). Something like this should work:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\myTest.xls", ReadOnly:=True
```

Make sure to include a backslash, since the workbook path doesn't end with one.

Comment: Works quite well. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

`Filename` is relative to the current Excel directory (which is different from the directory in which an opened document is).

You change the current directory by using `ChDir "x:\new\path"`.

But what you actually want to do is:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=EnsureSlash(ThisWorkbook.Path) & "myTest.xls", ReadOnly:=True
```

, where `EnsureSlash` is your custom function that appends a backslash (`\`) to the end of the string, if it's not already there (because `ThisWorkbook.Path` ends with a slash when the path is the root directory, and doesn't otherwise).

Comment: I was looking exactly for this "relative to what?" information, thanks!