# Dialog Box for Save As location in VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to export a file as a PDF as part of a larger macro.  However, I'd like the user to have the option of saving the file to a directory of his or her choosing, and I think this would be easiest with a browsing dialog box.  However, I can't figure out how to pull one up.  Currently, my code reads as follows.

```
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Users\<filepath>\11.08E PT5 Executive Summary - v3.2.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, From:=1, To:=3, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

I'd like to replace  with the result of the dialog box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Application.GetSaveAsFilename`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff195734.aspx).

```
dim v as variant
v = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("11.08E PT5 Executive Summary - v3.2.pdf", "PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf")

if vartype(v) = vbString then
  ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=v, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, From:=1, To:=3, OpenAfterPublish:=True
end if
```

Comment: Late to this thread but wondering, what is the reason or logic behind the `From:=1, To:=3` portion.  I am learning and don't quite follow why this is there or what it does.

Comment: Also, in doing it this way, how does the program know what the default file path will be when the save box comes up?

Comment: @Rivers31334 The `From:=1, To:=3` is in fact irrelevant to the question. I copied it from the OP's code because that's what they had. It is supposed to only save pages from 1 to 3, but this also [requires `Range:=wdExportFromTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb256835%28v=office.12%29.aspx) which the OP did not have, so it might have no effect after all. The default file path is the [current directory](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5944101/11683).