# Workbook.open randomly fails

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that uses workbook.open to open a download link for an excel file.

```
Set wkbWebWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("sample")
```

On my machine, this always works. On some machine, it sometimes work. And on my other mchine, it never works. I always get the error "Sorry, we couldn't open link".

I really don't know what's wrong with it anymore

Answer (score 0):

You should include the path to "sample" as a full file path for more reliable results.

Here's another StackExchange thread with more details:

[Workbooks.Open Method in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944068/workbooks-open-method-in-vba)