# Excel 64-bit returning "File not found: UKRM_EncodeEIB_D.dll.dll"

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

We have been attempting to use a macro function to encode a string for barcode conversion. We have been using the freely available Royal Mail Licence Barcode Encoder found at: http://www.royalmail.com/business/system/files/Royal-Mail-Licence-Barcode-Encoder-November-2014_0_0_0.zip. The eoncodier can be found in Licence Barcode Encoder090913 > Barcode > Encoder & Decoder Specs > EIB Barcode_Encoder_EXE > sampleUKRM_EncodeEIBsprdsht.xlsm. The module we're interested in is Barcode_D.bas, found in the same folder as the sample spreadsheet.
The file listed at above includes a sample excel sheet within which the function is applied. When we open the workbook, we can see the encoded string. However, when we save or attempt to edit it (e.g. to add new data fro encoding), the macro stops working. We hypothesised that this was due to the macro used being applicable to only a  32 bit version of Excel, so we added the appropriate content to the macro script to enable compatibility 64-bit excel. When we attempt to create a new workbook to include the module, following the steps in the Encoder guide, but still get the same error eventually. This is the macro that comes with the file:

```
Public Declare _
Function encode_eib_d Lib "UKRM_EncodeEIB_D.dll" (ByVal inInfoID As String, ByVal inVersionID As String, ByVal inClass As String, _
    ByVal inFormat As String, ByVal inLicenseNum As String) As Variant

Function ENCODE_D(inInfoID As String, inVersionID As String, inFormat As String, inClass As String, inLicenseNum As String) As Variant
    Dim error As Integer

    ChDrive (ActivePath())
    ChDir (ActivePath())

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    ENCODE_D = encode_eib_d(inInfoID, inVersionID, inFormat, inClass, inLicenseNum)

ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ENCODE_D = Err.Description
    End If


End Function



Function ActivePath() As String
     '
     '****************************************************************************************
     '       Function    returns the local path, i.e., the path to the current active "file"
     '                   or object
     '       Limitations:  MS applications only
     '
     '****************************************************************************************
     '
    Dim ApplName    As String
     '
     '           fetch application name and strip off "microsoft"
     '
    ApplName = LCase(Application.Name)
    ApplName = Right(ApplName, Len(ApplName) - 10)
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case ApplName
    Case "access"
        ActivePath = accPath
    Case "excel"
        ActivePath = xlPath
    Case "outlook"
        ActivePath = "**not defined**"
    Case "powerpoint"
        ActivePath = pptPath
    Case "project"
        ActivePath = projPath
    Case "visio"
        ActivePath = visPath
    Case "word"
        ActivePath = wrdPath
    Case Else
        ActivePath = "**not defined**"
    End Select
End Function
Function accPath() As String
    accPath = CurrentProject.Path
End Function
Function xlPath() As String
    xlPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
End Function
Function pptPath() As String
    pptPath = ActivePresentation.Path
End Function
Function projPath() As String
    projPath = ActiveProject.Path
End Function
Function visPath() As String
    visPath = ActiveDocument.Path
End Function
Function wrdPath() As String
    wrdPath = ActiveDocument.Path
End Function
```

We then adapted it for 64-bit via the PtrSafe attribute as we are running 64-bit Excel:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe _
Function encode_eib_d Lib "UKRM_EncodeEIB_D.dll" (ByVal inInfoID As String, ByVal inVersionID As String, ByVal inClass As String, _
    ByVal inFormat As String, ByVal inLicenseNum As String) As Variant

Function ENCODE_D(inInfoID As String, inVersionID As String, inFormat As String, inClass As String, inLicenseNum As String) As Variant
    Dim error As Integer

    ChDrive (ActivePath())
    ChDir (ActivePath())

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
    ENCODE_D = encode_eib_d(inInfoID, inVersionID, inFormat, inClass, inLicenseNum)

ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ENCODE_D = Err.Description
    End If


End Function



Function ActivePath() As String
     '
     '****************************************************************************************
     '       Function    returns the local path, i.e., the path to the current active "file"
     '                   or object
     '       Limitations:  MS applications only
     '
     '****************************************************************************************
     '
    Dim ApplName    As String
     '
     '           fetch application name and strip off "microsoft"
     '
    ApplName = LCase(Application.Name)
    ApplName = Right(ApplName, Len(ApplName) - 10)
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case ApplName
    Case "access"
        ActivePath = accPath
    Case "excel"
        ActivePath = xlPath
    Case "outlook"
        ActivePath = "**not defined**"
    Case "powerpoint"
        ActivePath = pptPath
    Case "project"
        ActivePath = projPath
    Case "visio"
        ActivePath = visPath
    Case "word"
        ActivePath = wrdPath
    Case Else
        ActivePath = "**not defined**"
    End Select
End Function
Function accPath() As String
    accPath = CurrentProject.Path
End Function
Function xlPath() As String
    xlPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
End Function
Function pptPath() As String
    pptPath = ActivePresentation.Path
End Function
Function projPath() As String
    projPath = ActiveProject.Path
End Function
Function visPath() As String
    visPath = ActiveDocument.Path
End Function
Function wrdPath() As String
    wrdPath = ActiveDocument.Path
End Function
```

We keep getting stuck with the dll error ("File not found: UKRM_EncodeEIB_D.dll"), despite the dll and workbook being in the same directory. Would someone be able to look at the macro and tell us where we are going wrong? I'm not an Excel expert, so any help would be appreciated. Will provide any other information as required, but if you can get the "sampleUKRM_EncodeEIBsprdsht.xlsm" file to produce a 36 character string from the data fields, including new entries, it would be tremendous. **Note we get the same error in MS Access.**

Comment: `despite the dll and workbook being in the same directory` - that's not important. [Excel's current directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5944101/11683) is. Then one you are setting to random things in `ENCODE_D` before calling `encode_eib_d`.

Comment: I unzipped the EXE folder into a temp directory and the macro ran without errors. See @GSerg comment.

Comment: UKRM_EncodeEIB_D.dll is x86 and won't run on x64 Office. But seems like they provide the sources and you can build an x64 version youself.