# Is there a way for Workbooks.Open to change user name when opening a workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a VBA code for a team of people that includes opening and closing a spreadsheet as shown:

`Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\JohnDoe\Box\Operations\Information\Projects\sample.csv"`

Although when someone else runs the code, it doesn't work as their name is different and it cant find the sheet. s there anyway I can alter the code so that it automatically updates the user name so that it can find the sheet when someone else runs it?

So for example if someone named Jane Doe is running the code, it will update to:

`Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\JaneDoe\Box\Operations\Information\Projects\sample.csv"`

When I run the sheet it works for me but when someone else runs it. The code cannot find the sheet as the username does not update.

Comment: Replace the username with a call to `Environ("UserName")` to get the username. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/environ-function

Comment: `"C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\Box\Operations`

Comment: Note: it would be better to store the files on a server that everyone can see, as that particular file may or may not be in that local location.

Comment: Duplicated question. Even when a response given will work, the path you are trying to use is not the best way to do it (It's possible to move windows user folders to different locations not always with the path pattern you wrote - mine for example is in "D" unit).

I recommend to use ThisWorkbook.Path and search stackoverflow always before asking. I found it duplicated and solved for example here:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944068/workbooks-open-method-in-vba